# Giving a list a partial order in Isabelle/HOLCF

Tags: isabelle

I would like to make a list datatype an instance of a poset from Porder.thy in HOLCF.  My attempt is as follows:

```
theory Scratch
imports Porder Representable
begin

datatype 'a myList = 
  Nil |
  Cons 'a "'a myList"

instantiation myList :: (below) below
begin
  definition below_list_def:
    "(x ⊑ y) = (case x of Nil ⇒ True | 
    Cons a xs ⇒ (case y of Nil ⇒ False |
    Cons b ys ⇒ a ⊑ b ∧ xs ⊑ ys))"
  instance ..
end
```

I realize that "definition" does not support the recursive definition I am using, and I should be using something like "fun" or "fixrec".  However, I do not know how to use those commands in this context.  Every example I have found online for making an instance of po uses a non-recursive datatype.  What is the best way to make a recursive datatype an instance of below and po?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fun` in this local context, you just have to give it the right name, i.e. the name of the function suffixed by "_" and the instantiated type name, in this case `below_myList`.

Then your example rewrites to:

```
instantiation myList :: (below) below
begin
  fun below_myList where
    "Nil ⊑ xs = True"
  | "Cons x xs ⊑ Nil = False"
  | "Cons x xs ⊑ Cons y ys = (x ⊑ y ∧ xs ⊑ ys)"
  instance ..
end

lemma "Nil ⊑ Nil"
  by simp
```